# cuDNN Error ARCH_MISMATCH on a Kepler GPU

Tags: cuda, cudnn, aleagpu

I'm just running the Alea TK samples. As long as I don't activate cuDNN things work will except for the CNN, since it uses Pooling2D which relies on cuDNN.

If I now activate cuDNN (via app.config) I get this error `[cuDNN Error] ARCH_MISMATCH` as soon as I call `Context.GpuContext(0)`.

If I run Context.GpuContext(0) without cuDNN I can clearly see, it's my 'GT 730' which should have compute 3.0 capabilities.

Any idea, what's going wrong here?

[image: MyDevidce]

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong. The GPU you have is (I guess) a GT730 DDR3, which is a compute capability 2.1 device and incompatible with cuDNN

Comment: Why the down vote? I'd appreciate an explanation at least.

Comment: lol some people in this tag are like that unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different versions of the GT-730, and they don't have the same CC :

> GeForce GT 730 : 3.5
>
> GeForce GT 730 DDR3, 128bit : 2.1

Source : [CUDA GPUs](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus), select *"CUDA-Enabled GeForce Products"* category.

If you have, as said by talonmies, the DDR3 & 128bit version, your CC is not sufficient for what you are trying to achieve.

You can either change your requirements (using other software, writing your own...) or change your GeForce graphics card.